# A property about Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a integrable function. I know that if $|f|$ is integrable, then
$$\Bigg| \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\; dx\Bigg| \leq  \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|\; dx. \tag{1}$$

**Question.** The property $(1)$ implies
$$\Bigg| \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\; dx\Bigg|^2 \leq  \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|^2\; dx? \tag{2}$$

Comment: needs b-a on the rhs

Comment: But by Cauchy-Schwarz $$\Bigg| \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\; dx\Bigg|^2 \leq (b-a)\cdot  \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|^2\; dx.$$

Comment: Let $f(x) = 1$. Then

$$ \left|\int_0^2 f(x) dx\right|^2 = 4,$$

while

$$ \int_0^2 |f(x)|^2 dx = 2.$$

The $b-a$ is necessary.

Comment: @User203940 Add that as an answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property (2) is not true. For example, take $f(x) = 1$ on the interval $[0,2]$. We have

$$ \left| \int_0^2 f(x) dx \right|^2 = 4$$
while
$$ \int_0^2 |f(x)|^2 dx = 2.$$